# BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google AdWords fails when importing reports for large accounts

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I'm having troubles with the [BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google AdWords](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer) scheduled export of some reports for a number of large accounts. The transfer was correctly set up, and it works perfectly on small and medium size accounts. However, on large accounts, I haven't been able to import a single day in over a month.

Inspecting the error logs, it seems a problem with `INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS`. This is quite weird though because I don't have any issue retrieving data from the Adwords API directly.

Below is an example of the logs for one import.

`Started     Oct 22, 2017, 7:40:00 AM
Ended   Oct 22, 2017, 7:17:09 PM
Run Name    projects/<project_id>/locations/us/transferConfigs/<another_id>/runs/<run_id>
Log Messages
    generic::unavailable: Error while processing report for table 'Ad'. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.ERROR_GETTING_RESPONSE_FROM_BACKEND</type><trigger>Unable to read report data</trigger><fieldPath   Oct 22, 2017, 7:03:24 PM
    generic::unavailable: Error while processing report for table 'Ad'. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.ERROR_GETTING_RESPONSE_FROM_BACKEND</type><trigger>Unable to read report data</trigger><fieldPath   Oct 22, 2017, 6:24:03 PM
    generic::unavailable: Error while processing report for table 'Ad'. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.ERROR_GETTING_RESPONSE_FROM_BACKEND</type><trigger>Unable to read report data</trigger><fieldPath   Oct 22, 2017, 5:45:24 PM
    generic::unavailable: Error while processing report for table 'Ad'. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.ERROR_GETTING_RESPONSE_FROM_BACKEND</type><trigger>Unable to read report data</trigger><fieldPath   Oct 22, 2017, 5:09:58 PM
    generic::unavailable: Error while processing report for table 'Ad'. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.ERROR_GETTING_RESPONSE_FROM_BACKEND</type><trigger>Unable to read report data</trigger><fieldPath   Oct 22, 2017, 4:35:58 PM
    generic::unavailable: Error while processing report for table 'Ad'. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.ERROR_GETTING_RESPONSE_FROM_BACKEND</type><trigger>Unable to read report data</trigger><fieldPath   Oct 22, 2017, 4:01:31 PM
    generic::unavailable: Error while processing report for table 'Ad'. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.ERROR_GETTING_RESPONSE_FROM_BACKEND</type><trigger>Unable to read report data</trigger><fieldPath   Oct 22, 2017, 3:27:40 PM
    generic::unavailable: Error while processing report for table 'Ad'. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.ERROR_GETTING_RESPONSE_FROM_BACKEND</type><trigger>Unable to read report data</trigger><fieldPath   Oct 22, 2017, 2:54:47 PM
    generic::unavailable: Error while processing report for table 'Ad'. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.ERROR_GETTING_RESPONSE_FROM_BACKEND</type><trigger>Unable to read report data</trigger><fieldPath   Oct 22, 2017, 2:22:26 PM
    generic::unavailable: Error while processing report for table 'Ad'. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.ERROR_GETTING_RESPONSE_FROM_BACKEND</type><trigger>Unable to read report data</trigger><fieldPath   Oct 22, 2017, 1:50:29 PM
    Transfer load date: 20171019    Oct 22, 2017, 1:15:08 PM
    Error code 1 : TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK: . Will retry later.    Oct 22, 2017, 1:05:07 PM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 12:55:06 PM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 12:45:06 PM
    Error code 1 : TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK: . Will retry later.    Oct 22, 2017, 12:35:05 PM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 12:25:04 PM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 12:15:04 PM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 12:05:03 PM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 11:55:03 AM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 11:45:02 AM
    Error code 1 : TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK: . Will retry later.    Oct 22, 2017, 11:35:01 AM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 11:25:01 AM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 9:54:05 AM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 9:44:04 AM
    Error code 1 : TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK: . Will retry later.    Oct 22, 2017, 8:30:03 AM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 8:20:02 AM
    Error code 1 : TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK: . Will retry later.    Oct 22, 2017, 8:10:02 AM
    Error code 1 : TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK: . Will retry later.    Oct 22, 2017, 8:00:01 AM
    Error code 1 : INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS: . Will retry later.     Oct 22, 2017, 7:50:00 AM
    Error code 1 : TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK: . Will retry later.    Oct 22, 2017, 7:40:00 AM
    Dispatched run to data source with id 162523770456362   Oct 22, 2017, 7:40:00 AM`

The Customer Service told me to use this channel since the BigQuery team is monitoring it.

If this is a problem with the Quota limits, how can I increase the limit in order to the Data Transfer working for these large accounts?

Many thanks!

Comment: If any issue persists, please report at  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68378644 they will re-open to examine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the long wait.

The rollout is done. When the error happens, we will just skip the particular table.

Also we added one more option "Exclude Removed/Disabled Items" (see attachment). If you check that, we won't pull deleted items/stats for you -- probably you should try this.
[image]
Thank you again for using our service!

Comment: Hi @xuejian! The imports seem to work now. I still see some insufficient tokens errors here and there but I think that has to do with the fact that I was trying to refresh the import for a 3 months period on 10+ accounts at the same time. I'll let you know later next week if the problem has been fully solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please ignore the insufficient tokens if no other error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. 
It's a known issue: probably you have too many deleted Ads in the account, which blocks the download.
We are working with adwords team to fix this, but that will probably take 2-3 months.
A potential workaround: is it OK to skip the 'Ad' table, if it cannot be downloaded? By doing that you can at least get other tables.
(The workaround is not there yet, but we could implement it quickly if people can accept it)

Comment: Thank you for the reply @xuejian, the workaround would be a nice thing to have indeed! Do you have an estimate of when this could be implemented?

Comment: Considering our holiday season policy, best estimation is, it will be available in 2-3 weeks. 
You could track status here via the following ticket:
https://issuetracker.google.com/68378644

Comment: Sorry for the long wait.